# GPS device that save location on SD card without the need of SIM card

Tags: gps, microsd, sd-card

I'm looking for a device that can record GPS coordinate and save them to SD card, without the need for SIM card. I need this so I can tag my photos on laptop when I get home. GPS for my camera is way too big, I want something I can put in my backpack and forget about and only need to charge it once in a day (it would be nice if the battery last few days).

The only devices I've seen are GPS navigation with a map and spy devices or localizators with sim card.

Ideal whould be device (small computer) that save single file each day to SD card. that can be read from SD card and processed. I already have script in python that tag my photos based on GPX  or CSV files created using Android app called GPS logger.

Do you know any devices like this? I have GPS in my phone but I always forget to turn it on when I'm shooting photos, because GPS consume more power and I can't have it always turn on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have personally used an Arduino with a [GPS module](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/gps-chips-gps-modules/9084085?cm_mmc=UK-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-PLA_UK_EN_Computing_%26_Peripherals_Whoop-_-GPS%20Chips%20%26%20GPS%20Modules_Whoop-_-9084085&matchtype=&aud-827186183886:pla-335746249196&gclid=Cj0KCQjw0Mb3BRCaARIsAPSNGpUS_Rb8vu6n6SVYof9by9xOfxTJ3j_rWSQZTexxtgyrwIY-fYI9Xa0aAiYpEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) an [SD Card module](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Adafruit/254?qs=GURawfaeGuAkwqCF4BmPzA%3D%3D&vip=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjw0Mb3BRCaARIsAPSNGpUB6pwW7tLGcliZbPF3GTVInCWD9KrZjl2jzG13OSDfclU97ou4oSsaAln7EALw_wcB) to plot GPS coordinates. This is a bit of a DIY project and requires some programming, but given your StackOverflow reputation this should not be an issue for you at all and has the added benefit of being customisable to your exact needs.

The Arduino can be powered using a powerbank which, depending on the size, would easily last more than a day.

Below is a map of the route which I took, the blue line is the path I walked and the red line is the GPS points read from the SD card - as you can see the results are quite accurate for an inexpensive system.

[image]